# Stack overflow exception for large data sets

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I tried solving this problem: http://projecteuler.net/problem=201 But the program below breaks for larger SET size(>20) throwing a stack overflow exception. Is there a memory leak happening? Could you please point out where? Also if the following implementation involves bad coding practice, please let me know. I'm trying to improve my amateur programming skills. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I edited the code below. I don't get any stack overflow exceptions now. But could anyone suggest me a better algorithm? Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <winsock2.h>
#define SET 100
#define SUBSET 50

class node
{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
};

using namespace std;
int sum(int A[SUBSET]);
void combCalc(int S[SET]);
bool search(node* head, int sum);
void appendIfUnique(int total, bool nullHeader);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   int S [SET];
   for(int i=1; i<=SET; i++)
   {
       S[i-1]= (int)pow((float)i,2);
   }
  combCalc(S);
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}

static node *head; 
static node *current = head;
void combCalc(int S[])
{
   int row=0, col=0;
   int elePos[SUBSET], B[SUBSET];
   bool nullHeader = true;
       for(int z=0; z<SUBSET; z++) // initializing elePos
       {
            elePos[z]=z;
       }

       bool notDone = true;
       while (notDone || col <(SUBSET-1))
       {B[col] = S[elePos[col]];
            if(col==(SUBSET-1)) //finished forming a subset
            {

                notDone = false;
                for(int q=(SUBSET-1); q>=0; q--) //incrementing from the last element
                {
                    if(elePos[q]<(SET-SUBSET+q)) //checking if the element has reached its maximum
                    {
                        notDone = true;
                        elePos[q]++;
                        for(int w=q+1; w<SUBSET; w++) //setting the trailing elements to its minimum
                        {
                            elePos[w]=elePos[q]+w-q;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(notDone){col=0;row++;}
                int total = sum(B);
                appendIfUnique(total,nullHeader);
                nullHeader = false;
            }
            else
            {
                col++;
            }
       }        
                int result = 0;
                for(node *pnode = head; pnode != current->next; pnode=pnode->next)
                    result = result + pnode->data;
                cout << result << endl; 
}


int sum(int A[])
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<SUBSET; i++)
    {
        total = total + A[i];
    }
    return total;
}

bool search(node* head, int sum)
{
    bool exists = false;
    node* pNode = head;
    while(pNode != NULL)
        {
            if(pNode->data == sum)  
            {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
            pNode = pNode->next;
        }
    return exists;
}

void appendIfUnique(int total, bool nullHeader)
{
    if(nullHeader){head = NULL;}
                if(!search(head,total))
                {
                    node *temp;
                    /*temp=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));*/
                    temp = new node();
                    temp->data = total;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    if(head == NULL)
                    {
                        head = current = temp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current->next = temp;
                        current = temp;
                    }
                }           
}
```

Comment: seems like a bit of number theory rather than brute force might help....?

Comment: Stack overflow indicates that you are using too much stack space. Try dynamically allocating some of the stack allocated arrays. Now, while that will solve the immediate problem, you might want to reconsider the algorithm

Comment: I can't help but think this post would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the static variables look suspicious to me. You have a recursive call `combCalc(S)` that depends on the static variables to get out

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ... stack overflow indicates also that you have too many stacks.

Comment: @jsantander: There is often a single stack, with multiple frames. Stack overflow is still that you are using too much stack, whether due to few stack frames with large objects or small frames but too many of them… But point taken: not only the size of the variables matters, how many levels of recursion are also an important factor (often more than the variables themselves, as you might get SO due to infinite recursion)

Comment: What is the base case for the `combCalc` function?  Please think about what condition(s) are necessary for the function to return before reaching the closing curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

1. Break point (in my system: cygwin g++) is SET=18 (17 works)
2. Problem is due to too much recursion [run it within a debugger] You have too many calls to `combCalc(S)` (in my case, it dies after 32K calls).

As it has been indicated in the comments, you should probably reconsider your algorithm. In the meantime, a simple modification is to remove the recursion (since it is not even a proper recursion):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   int S [SET];
   for(int i=1; i<=SET; i++)
   {
       S[i-1]= (int)pow((float)i,2);
   }
   while(combCalc(S)) { } // <--- keep calling while combCalc is true
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

by making combCal() return a bool:

```
bool combCalc(int S[]) // <--- MODIFY (check also the forward declaration)
{

       ...

       if(notDone || col <(SUBSET-1))
       {
            ...

            return true; // <--- MODIFY return true... I need to keep calculating.
       }
       else
       {
                int result = 0;
                for(node *pnode = head; pnode != current->next; pnode=pnode->next)
                    result = result + pnode->data;
                cout << result << endl;
                return false; // <--- MODIFY return false.... we're done
       }
}
```

The above is just a minimum modification. I'm not even sure it solves the problem correctly since I haven't really looked at the algorithm.

You should consider:

1. Use a less brute force algorithm
2. Move the while loop within the combCalc()... so you will be having a single call... and in this case you probably can remove the static variables and make them simple local variables.
3. Consider not using `#define` for constants.
4. Consider using STL structures... instead of your own home grown ones. This will remove some of the concerns below.
5. Consider not using `malloc` but using `new` (more C++)
6. You're not using `free` this means that the memory you allocated will not be released. (use `delete` if you're using `new` or `delete []` if you did `new []`)

Comment: I modified the program as you suggested by using a while loop inside the function instead of a recursive function and I don't get any exception now. But the program is running forever. Can anyone suggest me a better algorithm for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @user3651245 you should accept this answer since it answers your question. If you now have a better question, by all means, file a new one. (**Edit** and editing the question to completely change it is not a nice thing to do after people have spent time on it)

Comment: How do I accept this as answer? I'm new to this site. Thanks.